# Material Angular Fill Grid Tile

Tags: css, angular-material2

Using https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview:

I created a `md-grid-list` which should have `2 cols` and inside each `md-grid-tile` I want to place a `md-card` which should fill the whole tile.

Currently the `md-grid-list` is looking like this:
[image]

The html code - without the second `md-card`:

```
  <md-grid-list cols="2" rowheight="2:1">
  <md-grid-tile>
  <md-card class="data-representer-card">
    <md-card-title>Pick up from where you left</md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
      <p>
        The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan. A small, agile dog that copes
        very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally bred for hunting.
      </p>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-actions>
      <button md-button>LIKE</button>
      <button md-button>SHARE</button>
    </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

How can I make the `md-card`stretch and fill the full area which is marked blue in the screenshot?

Comment: IMO, you should use this https://github.com/angular/flex-layout instead of `</md-grid-list>`. It is also documented in `Material 2`. It gives move features over `</md-grid-list>`.

Comment: @talentedandrew ok, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @talentedandrew

It took me a while to figure out how to include `flex-layout` but now it is working as expected:

I followed along this guides successively:

- https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Developer-Setup
- https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Fast-Starts

After that I get the expected result after refactoring my html code:

```
  <md-card class="data-representer-card" fxFlex="50">
    <md-card-title>Pick up from where you left</md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
      <p>
        The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan. A small, agile dog that copes
        very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally bred for hunting.
      </p>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-actions>
      <button md-button>LIKE</button>
      <button md-button>SHARE</button>
    </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>

  <md-card class="data-representer-card" fxFlex="50">
    <md-card-title>Pick up from where you left</md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
      <p>
        The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan. A small, agile dog that copes
        very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally bred for hunting.
      </p>
    </md-card-content>
    <md-card-actions>
      <button md-button>LIKE</button>
      <button md-button>SHARE</button>
    </md-card-actions>
  </md-card>
```

Now both card elements are next to each other and are at the top of the view.